# Should I use foreign key or CHECK CONSTRAINT to track which user is CRUD-ing the database?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, database-design, relational-database

Database tables:

```
employees
(employeeID int PK,
...
isVipUser boolean DEFAULT 0,
loadUser int FK REFERENCES employees (employeeID)),

teams
(teamID int PK,
...
loadUser int FK REFERENCES employees (employeeID)),

someotherTable
(someotherTableID int PK,
...
loadUser int FK REFERENCES employees (employeeID))
```

*loadUser* is the last column in every table across the database used for tracking which employee entered which row. It references employeeID in the employees table. Because of this there is a relation between employees and every other table in the database.

Business rule: data in some tables can be altered by any user, in others only by VIP users and in some only by current user.

Is it a good design strategy to remove employeeID FK across the database, set up three CHECK constraints (each calling it's own UDF) to check if loadUser is among vip/any/current user(s) and pin one of them on each table (according to the specific need of a table)?

Comment: I personally find the foreign key to an employee awful. You have eliminated the possibility of deleting that row from the table. In some systems this could be ok if you use soft deletes but in others it ends up being a total nightmare. That being said why can't you control this from the application instead of in the database?

Comment: @SeanLange No employee should ever be deleted. There are other ways to mark one as pasive/ex/dead. I am trying to make the database as stand-alone as I can because there is an issue with the application layer strategy. I am planing this as if there will only be rudimentary front end layer on top. All the decision making is at the db level (if possible, off course).

Comment: It is certainly possible but all those UDFs are going to have an impact on performance.

Comment: I would leave the FK relationship and add the UDFs.

Comment: @SeanLange Yep, that is my mail concern - will it become noticeable at one point...

Comment: You don't know the impact until you test.

Comment: Agreed with @Paparazzi. The FK is fine. The UDF will provide the customized level of detail you need.

Comment: You may want to consider implementing the interface to the DB using stored procedures. Grant users access to the SPs and revoke access to the underlying tables. Then you can implement, and reimplement, the business rules as needed behind an interface that can be tested independently and doesn't need to change. If you decide later that you need to log more information, e.g. last update time and user per row, or log all changes to audit tables, the application won't be affected. Additional rules, e.g. team members can modify data within their team, just update the SPs.

Comment: I Agree with all comments. HABO's suggestion seems the best to me. One benefit of stored procedures is encapsulation - Your application doesn't need to know what are the underlying tables - it only need to know what the stored procedures expose.